# Evaluating Trigonometric Limits

Tags: calculus

Suppose I am trying to evaluate a trigonometric limit of the sort:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}x\cot3x$$

From what I have read it is typically useful to try and compute the limit to see if it exists before manipulating, I would like to know how I could attempt to compute this since it has a triple angle to see if it exists. Is it necessary to manipulate this before computing other than converting $\cot3x=\dfrac{\sin3x}{\cos3x}$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this:
$$x\cdot\dfrac{\cos3x}{\sin3x} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{3x}{\sin 3x} \cdot \cos 3x.$$

Then, $$\lim_{x \to 0}x\cot3x = \left(\frac{1}{3} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x}{\sin 3x} \right) \left(\lim_{x \to 0}\cos 3x\right).$$

You should now hopefully recognize and be able to evaluate these limits!

Comment: Thanks for this, but my primary question is manipulation always necessary to compute the limit if its a double angle or triple angle?

Comment: Manipulation is not always necessary. For example the split limits above have $3x$ as the argument, but we can still evaluate them. Manipulation is necessary when we can't directly evaluate the limit. For example we can't plug in $x=0$ to $x\cot 3x$ because we'd be dividing by $0$.

Comment: @nitrous2 In mathematics, the answer to "is it always ..." is always *no*. The fact that you had $3x$ in that limit did not make much difference: it could be $\lim_{x \to 0}x\cot x$ or $\lim_{x \to 0}x\cot (35.29838x)$. (I doubt you'd find a nice identity for the latter).

Comment: So on the $\cos3x$, if I plug in 0 $\cos3(0)$, how do I find the value for it? Not a value on the unit circle.

Comment: What do you mean not on the unit circle? The trigonometric functions are directly related to the unit circle. [Check out this image.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/Trigonometry_675.gif) At $\theta = 0$, $\cos \theta$ has a value of $1$.

Comment: well for example $\cos(0)$ is $1$ as on the unit circle, I am confused about the 3 in $cos3x$.

Comment: The $3$ is like a weight. It affects the period of cosine. The larger the weight, the less time it takes for cosine to begin repeating again (i.e. the faster we travel around the unit circle). If you think of the $x$ as time, then at $x=0$, $\cos(3\cdot 0)$ still has gone nowhere, since $3\cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: Alright thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know $\tan x \sim x$ (and hence $\tan 3x \sim 3x$) as $x\to 0$, then the question will be more simpler.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\cot 3x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {x}{\tan 3x}=\frac13\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {3x}{\tan 3x}=\frac13.$$

May it helps.

Comment: Ahhh much easier method! Thanks!